# Cordova - Why is $http get request failing on android device but working on chrome

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I got that issue on my cordova project, created with angular and ionic. I've tried everything I could, and it ain't working.

Here's the code :

```
    function getSuccess(response) {
    $scope.modules = response.modules;
    $scope.list = $scope.modules;
    $scope.search = [
        {str: ""}
    ];
}

$http({method: 'GET',
        url: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/modules"
    })
    .success(getSuccess)
    .error(function (response){
        alert("Damned");
    });
```

Of course, the IP is valid, and works in the chrome browser ;)
That's in my controller. I already added `<access origin="*"/>` in my config file and it's still displays the "Damned" on my android device, after building.

Cordova version : 5.0.0
Android version : 5.1

Comment: `response` should contain details about the error. don't output a fixed(useless) error message when you can be told exactly what's wrong.

Comment: I actually wanted to use something like console.log, but i don't know how to do that in the application, any idea ? :/

Comment: even something like `alert(JSON.stringify(response))` could help. anything to get the contents of the error object out and viewable.

Comment: The alert output is "" :/

Comment: The issue remains the same with a $http.get(myurl); :/

Comment: install whitelist plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist (and I don't mess up with the ZOHANNNN)

Comment: I'll try it tomorow on the evening and i'll tell you, scrappy coco ;)

Comment: Success and error callbacks have more parameters : data, status, headers, config, statusText. Check the content of status and statusText to have an idea of the error.

Comment: @aorfevre you should write that as an answer so it can get accepted

Comment: I didn't have time to try it, sadly. Hope i can get home earlier tonight to check this out !

Comment: @aorfevre post your comment as an answer, i'll put +1000 at it. You just save my life ! Tyvm ! <3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

install whitelist plugin : [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)

Since Cordova 5.0.0, Whitelist plugin is mandatory for cross origin requests